# Why are some Java EE APIs implemented in Java SE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I've noticed recently about some APIs that are supposed to be part of Java EE, but seem to be implemented in Java SE. For example, there's JAX-WS, which is a Java EE API, but can be used completely in a Java SE project.

Is there anything I'm getting wrong? There are some APIs from Java EE implemented in Java SE out of the box? Where can I find information about what JEE APIs are available in JSE as well?

Comment: All APIs of Java SE are in Java EE: Java EE is based on Java SE. JAX-WS shouldn't have been in Java SE. It's deprecated since Java 9 and removed since Java 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java SE APIs are basically the Java Standard Library. There's a nice diagram on the [Java Platform Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/)

And here is a list of the "Base Libraries": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/index.html#langutil

which includes `java.lang`, math, collections, reflection, concurrency, logging, preferences, io, net .... (notice that many of these are not even widely used by the Java community, like logging - where slf4j-api is the de-factor standard).

Then, there's also the "Integration Libraries" that include things like JDBC (Database Access) and JNDI (things like LDAP), and "User Interface Libraries" (used to be Swing and JavaFX, but now it's back to only Swing).

The [Java EE APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/toc.htm) include many other things, like email and JAX-RS as you mention, which extend the Java libraries and in theory, should interact and work on top of the SE APIs, providing a comprehensive whole suited for enterprisey development.

They are not implemented by the JavaSE runtime!

However, each JavaEE API can be implemented independently by independent organisations (or anyone that has enough spare time to spend on the effort) and be used from a mostly Java SE application on their own. This is why there's lots of Servlet containers (Tomcat, Jetty, GlassFish and [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container)) available which implement the Servlet API and not much else!

It should be noted that quite recently, JavaEE has become officially the [JakartaEE](https://jakarta.ee/) project. There's a searchable list of projects [here](https://projects.eclipse.org/list-of-projects?combine=servlet&field_project_techology_types_tid=All&field_state_value_2=All).

I'd also like to mention there's another [big set of APIs](https://www.osgi.org/developer/specifications/) that were developed in parallel with JavaEE in the [OSGi](https://www.osgi.org/) world, by the OSGi Alliance, that focussed on modularity of dynamic Java applications.

Finally, a competing framework, [Spring](https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework) is quite dominant in the Java world (and has actually influenced a lot the development of JavaEE itself), and even today, with beginner-friendly projects like [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) is probably more popular than JavaEE itself!

Myself, I like to stick with only Java SE, a few EE APIs like Servlets and JDBC *(**EDIT**: jdbc is in the standard lib!)* for essentials, and community driven projects (see for example [Micronaut](https://micronaut.io/) and [Vert.x](https://vertx.io/)) which are really cool stuff and are not based on any standards at all!

In summary, the Java world is big and there's a lot of variety! JavaEE is but a small part of it.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the info! I'm aware of some of this, but I still don't understand (for example), how I was able to run a full JAX-WS application using Java SE only, if JAX-WS is supposed (afaik) to be a Java EE exclusive API, and I didn't implement it by myself but used just a regular JDK.

Comment: It should be noted that Java SE either has, or will be soon, removed JAX-WS.

Comment: @LucianoMarti you must be using a servlet container implementation?! Just with the Java standard distribution, I don't know how you could process the annotations and start up a server using JAX-WS. Aren't you using https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/ or similar?

Comment: @Renato nope, just a simple JDK. Look at this hello world example: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the old SOAP stuff :D wow, this brings back bad memories :) I actually got this example running here... the JDK does include a simple HTTP server... it has even a SQL DB :D but yeah, looks like this was a mistake that maybe made sense in around 2002.

Comment: On Java 8 it works, but on Java 12: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.Endpoint

Comment: So, my mistake then haha. Thought they were the same thing and that was causing all the confusion. Thanks for that!